# Automating Facebook using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
print("opened facebook")
```

I  am using this code to open Facebook and the page opens.

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys("xxx")
sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "pass").send_keys("xxx")
sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login").click()
sleep(1)
```

Then log in to my account. After successful login, my chrome window closes in a few seconds.
Can someone tell me why?

Full Code:

```
import time
import os
import wget
import shutil
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


try:
    usr=""
    pwd=""

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    print ("Opened facebook")

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(usr)
    print ("Email Id entered")
    sleep(1)

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "pass").send_keys(pwd)
    print ("Password entered")

    driver.find_element(By.NAME,"login").click()

    sleep(100)
except Exception as e:
  print("The error raised is: ", e)
```

Answer (score 1):

The program will exit after executing code. Add below statements to keep program running:

```
time.sleep(300) #300 seconds i.e. 5 minutes

# close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I added this to my code still the same thing is happening.

Comment: did you put sleep(300) at the end of your code

Comment: yes I added it at the end.

Comment: put try except block around your code and print exception - we can see if any exception occuring

Comment: No exception is occurring. Until I log in the browser doesn't close.

Comment: try some other site - we can see if issue is related to specific site

Comment: The same thing is happening with Instagram. Until I log in it works fine.

Comment: pls share full code in question (except login name and password)

Comment: Updated the question with full code.

Comment: time.sleep(300) may not be the same as sleep(300), can you try with time.sleep ?

Comment: @SRP tried what you said still same thing is happening.

Comment: After login, can you print something and check if it's ok ?

Comment: @SRP print statement is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Stop Selenium from closing browser automatically
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# Chrome driver to run chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```